# laravel5.3 vue js methods not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue-resource, vue.js

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "getusers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)**

users.vue file

```
<template>
   <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.fname }}
      </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getusers: function () {
                this.$http.post('/users_search', this.formData).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }, function() {
                    console.log('failed')
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in the app.js file

```
   Vue.component('users', require('./components/users.vue'));

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
```

Comment: any other piece of code that shows where getusers is used? because here it isnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have several issues here, and that you have not provided enough information to debug the overall problem. I can at least let you know about a couple of issues I see:

1. In the pasted example above you are missing a closing `</template>` tag after the closing `</ul>` tag.
2. In your users component, you never call the `getusers()` method, you only define it. Based on your code, I assume you want to set `items` as the results of the `getusers()` method.

Comment: 1) sorry i missed to copy and paste the </template> and </ul> tags.

Comment: 2) <form  v-on:submit.prevent="getusers" >

Comment: You'll need to edit your original post so we can see the full block of code. Thanks!

Comment: while calling getusers() on form submit i need to pass the data to the above template and display it as an ajax call.. i am stuck with this error.. after running gulp command. i have this error [Vue warn]: Property or method "getusers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)

Comment: Is `<form v-on:submit.prevent="getusers" >` inside the 'users' component, or is it located somewhere else?

Comment: yeah its working when i moved form contents to user.vue component... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great. For reference, methods, data, etc. in vue can only be directly within the component. For sharing data between components, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Comment: Thanks....also form data is not posting with it...is there any other way! I had used this.formData to post

Comment: this.$http.post('/users_search', this.formData).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }, function() {
                    console.log('failed')
                })

Comment: @SriRag `var formData = new FormData()` then use `formData` (without this), check out `FormData`'s doc on mdn. Post another question if this comment is not enough.